# Datatable styling so bootstrap button appears on same row as other elements

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using jQuery DataTables plugin and Bootstrap on my rails site. I can't get my custom button and other table header elements to nest in the same row, They are stacked instead of being inline.

Any suggestions to get them all on the same line?

Here is some of the JavaScript I've used:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#products').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Blfrtip',
    buttons: [ {
      text: 'Pull my products',
      action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
        alert( 'Button activated' );
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

Comment: CSS `white-space: nowrap;`?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

#### SOLUTION #1

This is the most confusing part with using Bootstrap style for jQuery DataTables and it's undocumented so far. Bootstrap extension overrides default [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) which can be confirmed by viewing [its source code](https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.8/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js).

You have to use specially crafted [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option similar to shown below:

```
dom: 
    "<'row'<'col-sm-3'l><'col-sm-6 text-center'B><'col-sm-3'f>>" +
    "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
    "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
```

You can be as creative as you want by using Bootstrap `row` and `col-*` classes in the [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option.

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vckbwjqb/124/) for code and demonstration.

#### SOLUTION #2

You can also use direct insertion method as shown in [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) because default [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option used for Bootstrap styling is quite complex.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   initComplete: function(){
      var api = this.api();

      new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(api, {
         buttons: [
            {
               text: 'Pull my products',
               action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                  alert( 'Button activated' );
               }
            }
         ]
      });

      api.buttons().container().appendTo( '#' + api.table().container().id + ' .col-sm-6:eq(0)' );  
   }
});
```

Note that code differs from the example referenced above because there is an [issue](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/646) with DataTables 1.10.9 preventing direct insertion of buttons if there is no `B` character in [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option or [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option is not specified.

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vckbwjqb/125/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Wow.. just wow.. Thanks Gyrocode.. totally makes sense, but how in the world did you figure this one out?? One last question.. How do you add in a second custom button on that same line?

Comment: @ToddT, had the same problem and figured it out by inspecting the source code of the extension. jQuery DataTables is an excellent library but I wish this part was documented better.

Comment: Awesome.. How do you add a second custom button to that same line?

Comment: @ToddT, I'm still learning the new features in 1.10.8, but I assume it should be done as in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vckbwjqb/1/).

Comment: Once again.. thanks so much! I tried that but missed the comma between the two buttons..

Comment: +1 @Gyrocode.com great stuff, been looking for something like this for a while! Not sure if the docs always displayed this info but it also appears to be in there now under the styling section https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

Comment: Also, because I wanted to use icon buttons I used a slightly different approach. So anybody who is interested see this fiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/vckbwjqb/2/

Comment: @Will.Harris, added more details with proper way to use direct insertion.

Comment: Thank you very much! This pointed me in the right direction.

BTW, if anyone tried this on version 1.10.15 and didn't get it working, then you need to install the Buttons extension which you can find here: https://datatables.net/download/release and, furthermore, to get the buttons to look more Bootstrap-3-like, you need to use the `className` option within the button definition like so: `className: 'btn btn-primary'`. Also, here's the documentation page for buttons in general: https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons

Comment: @ToddT, Your example on the jsfiddle worked like a charm for me!! Awesome. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 9):

In my case I just added these styles:

```
.dataTables_length,.dataTables_filter {
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put two divs: one for the datatable buttons and other for your custom code

```
       var table = $("#tbl_oferta").dataTable({
                dom: '<"pime-grid-button"B><"pime-grid-filter">frtip',
        ...
       });

       $("div.pime-grid-filter").html('<b>Custom tool bar! Text/images etc.</b>');
```

Then define div class in your css:

```
.pime-grid-button{float:left}
.pime-grid-filter{float:left;margin-left:10px}
```

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mlTI.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it.

```
"dom": '<"row"<"col-6"<"d-flex justify-content-start"<""l><"ml-4"i>>><"col-6"<"d-flex justify-content-end"<""f>>>>tp'
```

Also add some custom CSS to make things appear more inline.

```
div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_info{
   padding-top: 0.2em !important; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In My case, I just added this CSS

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length {
    float:left;
    position: absolute;
}
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add buttons in toolbar menu like shown below:

```
        initComplete: function(){
            $("div.toolbar").html('<input type="button");          
        }
```

then add this toolbar to DOM element of Datatables as shown below:

```
    dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-2'l><'toolbar'><'col-sm-8'f>>" +
                     "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                     "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
```

One can align this toolbar using css like below:
.toolbar {
float: left;
margin-left: 60px;
}

Answer (score -3):

Have a look at documentation of DataTable [Here](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/dom_toolbar.html).

try this `dom: '<"toolbar">frtip'`

Comment: Yea even that example stacks the search bar and the text they inserted.. see here http://live.datatables.net/coqisori/1/

Comment: `.toolbar {
    float: left;
}` add this. it  ill work like a charm.

Comment: That will not work correctly with Bootstrap styling. Besides you missed the `B` option.

Answer (score -3):

Put `style="display: inline"` on the elements you want to display inline.

Comment: Sounds good, but how do you attach a class to both a custom button and the items in the header of the Datatables plugin??

Comment: Why can't you?   Post your code so I can see what you mean.