# How do I align pageLength, export buttons, and search bar in semanticui DataTable?

Tags: javascript, css, datatables

I'm really not that fluent with JS and CSS, so I am having a hard time finding out how I could achieve the look in the image below for my data table:

[image: data table]
I basically want to divide the row into three columns with widths 4-8-4 to fit the page length, export buttons, and search bar.

I patterned my `DataTable` from [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/styling/semanticui.html). The only difference is that I removed the `lengthChange: false` in the javascript. I tried playing around with the dom options but I've got no luck on that.

I also found a solution for the same problem from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32252616/datatable-styling-so-bootstrap-button-appears-on-same-row-as-other-elements), but it uses bootstrap. I have no idea how I could modify it for `semanticui`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the following [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option:

```
dom:
  "<'ui grid'"+
     "<'row'"+
        "<'four wide column'l>"+
        "<'center aligned eight wide column'B>"+
        "<'right aligned four wide column'f>"+
     ">"+
     "<'row dt-table'"+
        "<'sixteen wide column'tr>"+
     ">"+
     "<'row'"+
        "<'seven wide column'i>"+
        "<'right aligned nine wide column'p>"+
     ">"+
  ">",
```

In your case DO NOT use this code from the [example](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/styling/semanticui.html) you have mentioned:

```
table.buttons().container()
    .appendTo( $('div.eight.column:eq(0)', table.table().container()) );
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks @Gyrocode.com! I think I somehow get the idea of writing a custom dom better now from your solution. May I just know why I needed to omit `table.buttons().container().appendTo( $('div.eight.column:eq(0)', table.table().container()) );`. I just want to understand better what it actually does since JS is still confusing for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Whooper, `appendTo()` code allows to insert HTML for Buttons into existing structure and avoid using complex structure with `dom` option. In your case using `dom` option would be much clear than modifying HTML content with JavaScript and jQuery.